# Insert special character into a String variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I am new in **Java** and I am trying to solve this problem:

How to save below highlighted **string** into a **variable** ?

`( /[\+]+/.test(elements[i]) ) ? elements[i].replace(\"+\",\"_\") : elements[i];" +`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean but... `"( /[\\+]+/.test(elements[i]) ) ? elements[i].replace(\\\"+\\\",\\\"_\\\") : elements[i];\" +"` ?